# $\ell_p$ direct sum of $\ell_p$'s

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

If $H$ is a separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, then we can find a unitary isomorphism $H\cong\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}H_n$ where each $H_n$ is an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. If instead of $H$, I have $\ell_p$ ($1<p<\infty$), then what is the/an analogous (isometric) isomorphism statement? Should I be taking an $\ell_p$ direct sum of a countable collection of $\ell_p$'s?

Comment: Denote $\ell_p(S)=\{f:S\to \mathbb{C} : \Vert f\Vert_p<\infty\}$. Whenever $S=\bigsqcup_{\lambda\in \Lambda} S_{\lambda}$ we always have $$\ell_p(S)=\bigoplus_p \{\ell_p(S_\lambda):\lambda\in\Lambda\}$$ This easy generalizes to $L_p$-spaces